# Gmaps location not obtained while using ART

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, nexus-5, art

I've been trying to get the current location on my [Nexus 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_5). When I click on the location button on the bottom right corner it keeps showing "waiting for location", but nothing happens. But it does work fine in [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29).

Is it a bug or is it some setting?

Comment: Good question as I have a feeling ART is going to generate a lot of queries, and the answers below are going to be repeated a lot until ART is out of the WIP stage.

Answer (score 4):

ART is still a **work in progress** and things *may or may not* work as expected. You can't do anything about except wait for the application's developer coming with a fix and/or wait for ART to be more stable.

Answer (score 1):

ART is currently only included as an option so that developers can test their apps for compatibility, it doesn't offer benefits for normal people just running normal apps on their phones, quite the opposite in fact at the moment as many of them aren't compatible in their current version. There is a reason that the option to enable ART is hidden away in the hidden developer menu.